# How to pass csv mapped bean class to Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

I wrote code to read a csv file and map all the columns to a bean class.
Now, I'm trying to set these values to a Dataset and getting an issue.

```
7/08/30 16:33:58 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

If I try to set the values manually it works fine

```
public void run(String t, String u) throws FileNotFoundException {

    JavaRDD<String> pairRDD =  sparkContext.textFile("C:/temp/L1_result.csv");
    JavaPairRDD<String,String> rowJavaRDD = pairRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {

        public Tuple2<String,String> call(String rec) throws FileNotFoundException {
            String[] tokens = rec.split(";");
            String[] vals = new String[tokens.length];
            for(int i= 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                vals[i] =tokens[i];
            }

            return new Tuple2<String, String>(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        }
    });


    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy cpm = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    cpm.setType(funds.class);
    String[] csvcolumns = new String[]{"portfolio_id", "portfolio_code"};
    cpm.setColumnMapping(csvcolumns);

    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:/temp/L1_result.csv"));

    CsvToBean csvtobean = new CsvToBean();
    List csvDataList = csvtobean.parse(cpm, csvReader);

    for (Object dataobject : csvDataList) {
        funds fund = (funds) dataobject;
        System.out.println("Portfolio:"+fund.getPortfolio_id()+ " code:"+fund.getPortfolio_code());
    }

    /*  funds b0 = new funds();
    b0.setK("k0");
    b0.setSomething("sth0");
    funds b1 = new funds();
    b1.setK("k1");
    b1.setSomething("sth1");
    List<funds> data = new ArrayList<funds>();
    data.add(b0);
    data.add(b1);*/

    System.out.println("Portfolio:" + rowJavaRDD.values());


    //manual set works fine ///
    //  Dataset<Row> fundDf = SQLContext.createDataFrame(data, funds.class);
    Dataset<Row> fundDf = SQLContext.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD.values(), funds.class);
    fundDf.printSchema();
    fundDf.write().option("mergeschema", true).parquet("C:/test");
}
```

The line below is giving an issue: using `rowJavaRDD.values()`:

```
Dataset<Row> fundDf = SQLContext.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD.values(), funds.class);
```

what is the resolution to this? whatever values Im column mapping should be passed here, but how this needs to be done. Any idea really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Dataset fundDf = SQLContext.createDataFrame(csvDataList, funds.class);

Passing list worked!